# How do I control the entry point for the animation in chartjs line chart. I want all datasets to enter from the bottom of the chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, css-animations

I am using a line chart with chart js in react. Currently I have two datasets. By default the first ones animation appears to come in from the bottom of the chart, while the second dataset comes in from the top of the chart. I would like both animations to 'enter' from the bottom.

I have tried a couple variations of this in my options. Along with putting it directly into the datasets.

```
animations: {
   enter: {
       from: {
          y: 'bottom',
       },
   },
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the right syntax. In your options you can add

```
animation: {
   y: {from: 500}
},
```